# OpenCV: how to get image format if reading from buffer?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I read an image (of unknown format, most frequent are PNGs or JPGs) from a buffer.
I can decode it with `cv2.imdecode`, I can even check if it is valid (`imdecode` returns non-None).

But how can I **reveal the image type** (PNG, JPG, something else) of the buffer I've just read?

Comment: you can't. once it's a cv::Mat, or a numpy array, it does no more know, what it was made from.

Comment: Once you read the image data and store it into the buffer, that's it.  You can't determine what type of image it was because that's the purpose of decoding image data!

Comment: No-no-no. I get some raw image data (encoded with JPG, PNG, etc) in my web form processor. It may be broken, it may have incorrect extension. OpenCV decoder can choose the codec automatically and decode it. It can even check if it is correctly encoded (not damaged). But I still don't know how to get its correct file type (to set the extension of the file to save).

Comment: opencv does not look at filename-extensions, more at 'magic headers'. look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) to get an idea.

Comment: I know that I can't believe that my users will send my only correct files with correct extensions. And I know that OpenCV somehow reads the file headers when using `imdecode`. But I don't know how to get the file type from OpenCV.

Comment: OK, so they are uploading the image to a web form?  If that's the case, you can check the header information and see which file type it is.  For example, JPEG starts with `0xFFD8`: http://www.fastgraph.com/help/jpeg_header_format.html .  PNG starts with `0x 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header .  That link by @berak is much more comprehensive.

Comment: @Felix - Don't use OpenCV.  Simply examine first few bytes of the buffer and ascertain what type it is.

Comment: Well, OpenCV won't be a problem: I still have to use it to generate some thumbnails from the images (crop and resize operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard Python function`imghdr.what`. It rulez!

^__^